# AYUDA CON UNA CONSULTA EN MYSQL-SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo este store procedure con la siguiente consulta.

Al ingresar el nombre del equipo te muestra los últimos partidos que jugó, me gustaría poder insertar en en la columna de puntos los puntos que acumulo el equipo durante sus partidos.
En este caso el equipo del que me gustaría conocer los puntos sería **CRUZ AZUL**.

¿De qué forma podría lograrlo?
Se me ocurría hacerlo con un **CASE** pero al introducirlo dentro del **SELECT** me marca error.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_cons_partidos`(in no_equi char(30))
BEGIN
SELECT semana, local.nom_equipo, goles_loc, visitante.nom_equipo, goles_vis, ganador, puntos FROM partidos 
JOIN equipos local ON partidos.num_eqpo_loc = local.num_eqpo 
JOIN equipos visitante ON partidos.num_eqpo_vis = visitante.num_eqpo
WHERE local.nom_equipo= 'CRUZ AZUL' OR visitante.nom_equipo = 'CRUZ AZUL' ORDER BY semana;

END
```

[image: IMAGEN EN LA QUE SE MUESTRA LA TABLA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pudes utilizar un if dentro del select, quedaria de la siguiente manera, si gano el equipo gana 3 puntos si empata gana 1 punto.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_cons_partidos`(in no_equi char(30))
BEGIN
SELECT semana, l.nom_equipo, goles_loc, v.nom_equipo, goles_vis, ganador,
IF(p.ganador = no_equi,'3',IF(p.ganador = 'Empate','1','0')) AS 'Puntos' FROM partidos p
INNER JOIN equipos l ON p.num_eqpo_loc = l.num_eqpo 
INNER JOIN equipos v ON p.num_eqpo_vis = v.num_eqpo
WHERE l.nom_equipo= no_equi OR v.nom_equipo = no_equi ORDER BY semana;
END
```

Comment: Excelente me sirvió mucho, no se me había ocurrido usar un `IF` gracias por ayudarme.